# Matching multiple criteria efficiently in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm not quite sure how to word this but will try my best.

Below is a snapshot of a sheet I am working on to determine the global supply of a certain item.
I would like the last column to display it's overall availability for quick viewing.

[image]

I'm using the following, probably very overcomplicated formula to acheive this and was wondering if there was a more efficient way to arrive at this same result.

```
=If(AND(C116= "Extinct", E116 = "Endangered", F116 = "Extinct"), "Endangered", if(AND(C116= "Endangered", E116 = "Extinct", F116 = "Extinct"), "Endangered",If(AND(C116= "Endangered", E116 = "Endangered", F116 = "Extinct"), "Endangered",If(AND(C116 = "Extinct",E116 = "Extinct", F116 = "Extinct"),"Globaly Unavailable",If(AND(C116 = "Good",E116 = "Extinct", F116 ="Extinct"),"Available - Trend", If(AND(C116 = "Extinct",E116 = "Good", F116 = "Extinct"),"Available - Italia grp",IF(AND(C116 = "Extinct", E116 = "Extinct", F116 = "Good"), "Available - Rose", "Available")))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest assured it is **not** an overcomplicated formula for Google Sheets.
You probably have a difficult time reading it because it is all in just one long line.

By using  that can be easily fixed.

**While writing a formula in a cell**, pressing **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>** (on Windows) or **<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>** (on a Mac) keys which **will give a new line within the cell** thus making it easier to read and understand overall.
In the example below it is much easier to read the same beautiful, *"overcomplicated"* formula you already use.

```
=IF(AND(C116= "Extinct", E116 = "Endangered", F116 = "Extinct"), "Endangered", 
 IF(AND(C116= "Endangered", E116 = "Extinct", F116 = "Extinct"), "Endangered",
 IF(AND(C116= "Endangered", E116 = "Endangered", F116 = "Extinct"), "Endangered",
 IF(AND(C116 = "Extinct",E116 = "Extinct", F116 = "Extinct"),"Globaly Unavailable",
 IF(AND(C116 = "Good",E116 = "Extinct", F116 ="Extinct"),"Available - Trend", 
 IF(AND(C116 = "Extinct",E116 = "Good", F116 = "Extinct"),"Available - Italia grp",
 IF(AND(C116 = "Extinct", E116 = "Extinct", F116 = "Good"), "Available - Rose", "Available")))))))
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and thank you for the tip, i'll be sure to use this in the future. The formula in Question is one I wrote myself. I was curious if there was a more elegant solution that I hadn't arrived at because I'm relatively new to using sheets in this capacity.

Comment: Well... _"I was curious if there was a more elegant solution..."_ If that was your only concern then the answer is no. **There is no simpler/elegant way to express the conditions you are looking for.** 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: A follow up question. This formula is used in each individual cell. Is there a way to write a single forumla that would apply to the entire column?